# How to escape a question mark in R?

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to grep a vector of strings and some of them contain question marks.

I am doing:

`grep('\?',vectorofStrings)`
and getting this error:

`Error: '\?' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\?"`

How can I determine the proper escaping procedure for '?'

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to escape `\` as well:

```
vectorOfStrings <- c("Where is Waldo?", "I don't know", "This is ? random ?")
grep("\\?", vectorOfStrings)
#-----
[1] 1 3
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the `\\` or `fixed = TRUE` argument as in:

```
vectorofStrings <-c("hello.", "where are you?",  "?")

grep('\\?',vectorofStrings)
grep('?',vectorofStrings, fixed=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd guess `\` is used in R as a normal string escape character, so to pass a literal `\` to `grep` you might need `\\?`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have luck with backslash escaping, under windows grep. But I managed to make it work by the following:

```
grep [?]{3} *
```

That is, I enclosed the question mark in character class brackets ( `[` and `]` ), which made the special meaning inactive. The `{3}` part is not relevant to the question, I used it to find 3 consecutive question marks.