# Removing brackets with the text between them

Tags: r

Dataframe:

```
a<- as.character(rep("Sick (Atlas) (7:24)", 6))
b<- as.character(rep("20/08/2014", 6))
id<- as.character(rep("234", 6))
df<- data.frame(a,b,id)
df$a<-as.character(df$a)
```

[image]

I would like to remove `(Atlas)`. I tried

```
df <- as.data.frame(sapply(df,gsub,pattern="(Atlas)",replacement=""))
```

but it removes only Atlas and leaves brackets:

[image]

After reading the help for gsub, I assume that brackets are not regular expressions. So I tried to use backslash, but it did not work either.

```
df <- as.data.frame(sapply(df,gsub,pattern="\(\Atlas\)\",replacement=""))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you don't need `sapply` for that. you can either escape the brackets or use `fixed=TRUE`

Comment: What is your expected output?  If you need only `sick`, then `sub('\\s+.*', '', df$a)`

Comment: try `df$a <- gsub(pattern="\\(Atlas\\)",replacement="",df$a)`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. They all work fine. And I am sorry I posted a duplicate and stirred such a discussion. I had looked on the forum, but did not think that the questions I saw were answering my question. But I admit the omission. Could you please provide the link to the question that I duplicated?

Comment: @Vasile the link should be on top of your question, you may need to refresh the page. anyway : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex

Comment: @Cath Thank you. I saw that answer, but I quickly thought that the solution would remove all my brackets and whatever between them. Since I had some other parenthesis that I needed to keep, I just jumped to something else. But perhaps I could have explored it more and use for my question. Will try to do this in the future, before posting