# How to remove + (plus sign) from string in R?

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

Say I use gsub and want to remove  the following (=,+,-) sign from the string and replace with an underscore.

Can someone describe what is going on when I try to use the gsub with a plus sign (+).

```
test<- "sandwich=bread-mustard+ketchup"
# [1] "sandwich=bread-mustard+ketchup"

test<-gsub("-","_",test)
# [1] "sandwich=bread_mustard+ketchup"

test<-gsub("=","_",test)
# [1] "sandwich_bread_mustard+ketchup"

test<-gsub("+","_",test)
#[1] "_s_a_n_d_w_i_c_h___b_r_e_a_d___m_u_s_t_a_r_d_+_k_e_t_c_h_u_p_"
```

Comment: You can set `fixed = TRUE` or escape the "+".

Comment: great, Thanks it worked!!

Comment: R is a weak regex platform, in my opinion. If the majority of your work is of this type, it will be worth it to learn bash regex tools and/ or Perl.

Comment: `gsub("[+]", "_", test)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```
test<- "sandwich=bread-mustard+ketchup"
test<-gsub("\\+","_",test)
test
[1] "sandwich=bread-mustard_ketchup"
```

`+` is a special character. You need to escape it. Same as, for instance, `.`. If you google `regex` or regular expressions, you will find the corresponding lists of special characters. For instance, [here](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) `+` is described to indicate `1 or more of previous expression`. More about special characters, regular expressions and R can be found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex).

On a more general note, your above code could be written more efficiently by using:

```
 test<- "sandwich=bread-mustard+ketchup"
 test<-gsub("[-|=|\\+]","_",test)
 test
 [1] "sandwich_bread_mustard_ketchup"
```

Here I have used a construct that can basically be read as `[either this or that or something else]`, where `|` corresponds to `or`.

Answer (score 2):

```
test<-gsub("+","_",test,fixed = TRUE)
```

credit to Jota

Comment: This is also faster than using `\\+` without `fixed = TRUE`.

Answer (score -2):

I was also stuck. the following code worked for me.

```
test<- "sandwich=bread-mustard+ketchup"
test<-gsub("\\+","_",test)
test
[1] "sandwich=bread-mustard_ketchup"
```

However, one time it didn't work. I tried with [Ian's solution](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200792676) . It worked.