# Error: '\C' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""*G:\C"

Tags: r

```
pollutantmean("*G:\Coursera_JHU_Data_Science_Specialization\R Programming\Air Pollution\specdata\","sulphate")
```

> Error: '\C' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""*G:\C"

Comment: To use a \, you need to escape it - with another backslash. So \\. Or, you can convert it to forward slash /.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with special characters like \^$.?\*|+()\[{ in my regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex)

Answer (score -1):

Try using another backward slash as shown below

[image]