# Finding/Replacing "^" character using grep

Tags: r

Suppose I have a very simple data frame:

```
symbol <- c("A", "A^","B","C","C^")

df = data.frame(symbol)
```

Now imagine this is a very large dataframe so that I cannot easily list the rows in which the character "^" appears. 
How can I subset the rows with (or without) that character?

Notice that things like:

```
df[grep("^", df$symbol)
```

or regular subsetting will not work since the carat "^" is usually used to represent the beggining of a string.

Many thanks

Comment: you need to escape it , `df[grep("\\^", df$symbol),]` or `df[grep("^", df$symbol, fixed = TRUE),]`

Comment: The `?regex` docs that introduce the carat also explain this escaping rule (in Sotos' comment).

Comment: Thanks! Its solved now!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with special characters like \^$.?\*|+()\[{ in my regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex)

Answer (score 1):

Add fixed to the grep function, as follows:

```
df[grep("^", df$symbol, fixed=T),]
```