# Replace punctuation in string

Tags: r, regex

I want to replace the punctuation in a string by adding '\\' before the punctuation. The reason is I will be using regex on the string afterwards and it fails if there is a question mark without '\\' in front of it.

So basically, I would like to do something like this:

`gsub("\\?","\\\\?", x)`

Which converts a string "How are you?" to "How are you\\?" But I would like to do this for all punctuation. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't have experience with r, but `gsub("\\([.?])","\\\\$1",x)` or `gsub("\\([.?])","\\\\\\1",x)` should work.

Comment: There is no metacharacter escape function in _r_ ?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may be able to skip this step and just use the `fixed = TRUE` argument in your subsequent regex.

Comment: I think probably you have it backwards. The target string never has to be escaped. Only the regex string string with literal metachar's (ie. `?*+`,  etc) need to be escaped.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't think answering this question will help you get your real task done properly

Comment: [More good reading here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27721009/903061). In addition to `fixed`, another easy solution would be to use `\\Q` and `\\E` at the start and end of your strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **gsub** with the **[[:punct:]]** regular expression alias as follows:

```
> x <- "Hi! How are you today?"
> gsub('([[:punct:]])', '\\\\\\1', x)
[1] "Hi\\! How are you today\\?"
```

Note the replacement starts with '\\\\' to produce the double backslash you requested while the '\\1' portion preserves the punctuation mark.