# R, check if special character in string

Tags: r

How to use R to check if a string contains at least one of the following characters, `/\:*?"<>|`. Also, I hope the string can contain any other characters, e.g. `-`.

Actually these characters are the ones not allowed for windows directory (folder) name.

Comment: something like `myStr <- "this/string"; grepl("[[:punct:]]", myStr)` ?

Comment: @SymbolixAU, no because `grepl("[[:punct:]]", "-")` is true.

Comment: just make your pattern a bit more explicit: `myStr <- "thisstring"; grepl("/|:|\\?|<|>|\\|\\\\|\\*", myStr)`

Comment: @SymbolixAU Why not post that as an answer?  Akrun is asleep right now, go on!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - ha - yep, just tidying it up :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the pattern(s) you want to find in the string, then use `grepl` to find them

```
pattern <- "/|:|\\?|<|>|\\|\\\\|\\*"

myStrings <- c("this/isastring", "this*isanotherstring", "athirdstring")

grepl(pattern, myStrings)
# [1] TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

---

A break down of `pattern`:

if it were

```
pattern <- "/"
```

This would just search for "/"

The vertical bar/pipe is used as an 'OR' condition on the pattern, so

```
pattern <- "/|:"
```

is searching for either "/" OR ":"

To search for the "|" character itself, you need to escape it using "\"

```
pattern <- "/|:|\\|"
```

And to search for the "" character, you need to escape that too (and similarly for other special characters, ?, *, ...

```
pattern <- "/|:|\\?|<|>|\\|\\\\"
```

---

Reference:
[Dealing with special characters in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27721008/5977215)