# How to grep any format of percentages from a file in r?

Tags: r

I would like for my grep function to extract percentages from multiple files which are all formatted differently.  For example, they can be written in the following ways: (5%, 2.46%, 12.9%, 5 %, 2.46 %, 5 12.9 %, 5 percent, 2.46 percent, 5 per cent,...etc) and I want to make sure there is at least a space in front and behind to avoid extracting html codes, or things like:

```
<TD width="97%"></TD>
```

---

This is the code I am working with which is obviously wrong, I was thinking that maybe there was a way to place in placeholders like the asterisks below for the variety of numbers that it will be looking for like this:

```
  txt<-tryCatch(readLines(DS2[i,temp]), error = function(e) readLines(DS2[i,temp] ))
  t<-grep("**.**%", txt)
```

Comment: Something like `"[0-9]+\\.[0=9]+ *%"` should work. Both `*` and `.` are special characters in regex. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex and also this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to learn more.

Comment: Maybe `grep(" [0-9]{1,2}\\.[0-9]{1,2} ", text)`?

Comment: You'd be better off extracting the relevant attributes using xml parsing functions.  It's a lot easier.

Comment: Nice question, too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than write a single regex expression, it may be easier to do it in multiple steps. Using the examples you gave:

```
x <- c('5%', '2.46%', '12.9%', '5 %', '2.46 %', '5 12.9 %', 
       '5 percent', '2.46 percent', '5 per cent', 
        'etc..', '<TD width="97%"></TD>')

get_pct <- function(x) {
    x <- gsub('="[^"]+%"', '', x)
    x <- gsub('\\s*per\\s*cent|\\s*%', '%', x)
    is_pct <- grepl('\\d+(\\.\\d+)?', x)
    as.numeric(ifelse(is_pct, gsub('.*?(\\d+\\.?\\d*)%.*', '\\1\\2', x), NA))
}

f(x)
[1]  5.00  2.46 12.90  5.00  2.46 12.90  5.00  2.46  5.00    NA    NA
```

Here's the same thing step by step

```
# Eliminate percentages from html tags
x <- gsub('="[^"]+%"', '', x)
x
[1] "5%"              "2.46%"           "12.9%"           "5 %"             "2.46 %"          "5 12.9 %"       
[7] "5 percent"       "2.46 percent"    "5 per cent"      "etc.."           "<TD width></TD>"

# Standardize % symbol
x <- gsub('\\s*per\\s*cent|\\s*%', '%', x)
x
[1] "5%"              "2.46%"           "12.9%"           "5%"              "2.46%"           "5 12.9%"        
[7] "5%"              "2.46%"           "5%"              "etc.."           "<TD width></TD>"

# Find percentages
is_pct <- grepl('\\d+(\\.\\d+)?', x)

# Extract values
x <- ifelse(is_pct, gsub('.*?(\\d+\\.?\\d*)%.*', '\\1\\2', x), NA)
as.numeric(x)
[1]  5.00  2.46 12.90  5.00  2.46 12.90  5.00  2.46  5.00    NA    NA
```