# How to delete lines with a special character?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, grepl

I would like to delete the lines which contain the opening bracket "(" from my dataframe.

I tried the following:

```
df[!grepl("(", df$Name),]
```

But this does not track down the `(` sign

Comment: The `(` is understood by the grep expression as a part of the regex and not as a character. Try to escape the open brackets: `\\(` and see if this will work. You can find more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex

Comment: like this? df[!grepl(\\(, df$Name),]

Answer (score 6):

You have to double-escape the `(` with `\\`.

```
x <- c("asdf", "asdf", "df", "(as")

x[!grepl("\\(", x)]
# [1] "asdf" "asdf" "df"
```

Just apply this to your df like `df[!grepl("\\(", df$Name), ]`

You could also think about removing all puctuation characters by using regex:

```
x[!grepl("[[:punct:]]", x)]
```

As pointed out by @CSquare in the comments, [here is a great summary about special characters in R regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27721008/3250126)

---

Additional input from the comments:
@Sotos: Gaining performance with `pattern='('` and `fixed = TRUE` since the regex could be bypassed.

```
x[!grepl('(', x, fixed = TRUE)]
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `fixed = TRUE` instead of escaping that parenthesis i.e. (`x[!grepl('(', x, fixed = TRUE)]`) which is going to be more efficient as it bypasses the regex engine

Comment: `grep("(", x, fixed=TRUE, invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks for the hints, added it to the A.