# Concatenating special character with strings

Tags: r, string, paste

I want to concatenate some special characters with strings like

```
paste0("\code{", c("A", "B"), "}")
```

However, the following code works but appends extra `\`

```
paste0("\\code{", c("A", "B"), "}")
```

Would someone point out how to get this?

```
"\code{A}" "\code{B}"
```

Comment: This has been answered here,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex

Comment: How about `cat(paste0("\\code{", c("A", "B"), "}"))`