# Regular Expression to remove a letter and dot combination

Tags: r, regex, str-replace

I am trying to use regular expressions in R to remove text - either an 'X' or an 'X.' - from the front of a number.  I am new to regular expressions and having a hard time getting this to work.  I have tried every combination of X and . with or without the escape character that I could think of, including:

- `str_replace("X.4.89294e-05", "X.",'')` Result `"4.89294e-05"` but for fails for `str_replace("X4.89294e-05", "X.",'')`Result `".89294e-05"`
- `str_replace("X.4.89294e-05", "[X.]",'')` Result `".4.89294e-05"`
- `str_replace("X.4.89294e-05", "[X/.?]",'')` Result `".4.89294e-05"`
- `str_replace("X.4.89294e-05", "[X//.?]",'')` Result `".4.89294e-05"`
- `str_replace('X.4.89294e-0','X/.{0,1}','')` Result `"X.4.89294e-0"`
- `str_replace('X.4.89294e-0','[X/.{0,1}]','')` Result `".4.89294e-0"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A forward slash `/` is nothing special, the escape character is a backslash \. And generally, for regex in R,  you need 2 backslashes (one for R itself, one for the regex).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.` must be escaped. In R, you do that by adding a  `\\` before the `.` operator.

Read on the need for `\\` here: [Escape with a double backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27721009/1728224)

Like this:

```
txt = c("X.4.89294e-0", "X4.89294e-0")
str_replace(txt, "^X(\\.)?", "")
```

If you do not want to specifically match `X` or `X.` at the very beginning,  remove `^` from the example above to match it anywhere in the word.

Comment: Arg - I tried this combo but of course confusing `/` and `\\` will do it!  Thanks for this!

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why it was \\. instead of just \.

Comment: I've added a reference to another SO thread on the subject. It's explained way better than I ever could.

Answer (score 2):

You mean remove 'X' Or 'X.' From any digits?
Actually an single `.` in regex should be like this `\.`, so try `str_replace("X.4.89294e-05", "X\.?", "")` instead.

Comment: Need to double-escape, once for R, once for the regex. `"X\\."`

Comment: thanks, not familiar with R, just in common case for regex

Answer (score 2):

> remove text - either an 'X' or an 'X.' - from the front of a number

Taking into account that all your test cases contain a single `X` or `X.` at the start of the string, you may use

```
sub("^X\\.?(\\d)", "\\1", x)
str_replace(x, "^X\\.?(\\d)", "\\1")
```

Note that at the regex testing sites, you need to use a single backslash (a *literal* backslash) that is "coded" with the double backslash inside R string literals.

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `X` - an `X` char
- `\\.?` - `\.` matches a literal dot, and `?` is a quantifier making the regex engine match 1 or 0 consecutive occurrences of the `.` char
- `(\\d)` - a capturing group #1 that matches and stores in a memory slot any digit (`\d` matches any digit)
- `\\1` - inside a replacement argument, the reference to the value stored in Group 1 memory slot.

You may even use a `(?=\d)` lookahead based solution to check for a digit immediately to the right of the current location:

```
sub("^X\\.?(?=\\d)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
str_replace(x, "^X\\.?(?=\\d)", "")
```

Then, there is no need to use `\1` because the text matched with a lookahead is not put into the match and thus won't get removed during the `sub`/`str_replace`  operation.