# Remove period and spaces within column headings nested in a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames:

```
 mylist<-list(df1=data.frame(var1=c("a","b","c"), var.2= 
 c("a","b","c")), df2= data.frame(var1 = c("a","b","c"), 
 var..2=c("a","b","c")))
```

I would like to remove periods and spaces within the column headings of each data frame within the list.  The output would look like:

```
 mylist<-list(df1=data.frame(var1=c("a","b","c"), var2= 
 c("a","b","c")), df2= data.frame(var1= c("a","b","c"), 
 var2=c("a","b","c")))
```

I have tried the following:

```
 cleandf <- lapply(ldf, function(x) x[(colnames(x) <- gsub(".", "", 
 colnames(x), fixed = TRUE))])
```

Answer (score 2):

With Base R `setNames`:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) setNames(x, gsub("\\.", "", names(x))))
```

or with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

map(mylist, ~rename_all(.x, str_replace_all, "\\.", ""))
```

**Output:**

```
$df1
  var1 var2
1    a    a
2    b    b
3    c    c

$df2
  var1 var2
1    a    a
2    b    b
3    c    c
```

Answer (score 1):

I rename the columns in each data frame and then return the data frame. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27721009/1552004), double backslashes are needed as escape characters for the period.

```
lapply(mylist, function(x){names(x) <- gsub("\\.", "", names(x));x})

# $`df1`
#   var1 var2
# 1    a    a
# 2    b    b
# 3    c    c
# 
# $df2
#   var1 var2
# 1    a    a
# 2    b    b
# 3    c    c
```