# How can I use a sub function in R to change a factor level that has a plus (+ ) symbol?

Tags: r, rename, levels, recode

I ran into a hiccup using the sub() and gsub() functions in R to rename/change a factor level in R.  But I'm not sure why it is not working.

Scenario:
I have some survey data that several factors with levels that truncate the high value.  For example, a question about how many hours you worked last week stops at "89 + hrs".  I want to change this level to just "89" so I can use it numerically for other activities.
**I know several ways to do this--so I don't need various other level change options.**

I was following the instructions to use the sub() and gsub() functions from this site: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Renaming_levels_of_a_factor/
The concept is clear and straightforward.

Here is the initial example data:

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
x
[1] a b c d
Levels: a b c d
```

I can change level d to level 89

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
levels(x) <- sub("d", "89", levels(x))
x
[1] a b c 89
Levels: a b c 89
```

I'm fine when I introduce a space in the level:

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
levels(x) <- sub("d", "89 hrs", levels(x))
x
[1] a b c 89 hrs
Levels: a b c 89 hrs
```

I'm ok when I introduce a + symbol **into the new** factor level:

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
levels(x) <- sub("d", "89+ hrs", levels(x))
x
[1] a b c 89+ hrs
Levels: a b c 89+ hrs
```

But I get stuck when I'm trying to rename/change the level that has the + symbol into one without it:

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "89+ hrs"))
x
[1] a b c 89+ hrs
Levels:89+ hrs a b c

levels(x) <- sub("89+ hrs", "d", levels(x))
x
[1] a b c 89+ hrs
Levels: 89+ hrs a b c
```

Same issue when I include the *specific string* example from the linked site:

```
levels(x) <- sub("^89+ hrs$", "d", levels(x))
x
[1] a b c 89+ hrs
Levels: 89+ hrs a b c
```

The I get the same issue if I use gsub() instead of sub() as well.

The issue also happens if I had a * instead of a +, but works if it is a dot (.) instead of a +.  So I'm thinking it has something to do with certain special characters but not others.

Any thoughts why this isn't working with the + symbol and how I can use these functions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not quite a dupe, but on dealing with special characters in regex: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27721008/5325862

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sub()` function uses regular expressions by default and `+` is a special character for regular expressions. If you want to match a literal plus sign, use

```
levels(x) <- sub("89\\+ hrs", "d", levels(x))
```

or

```
levels(x) <- sub("89+ hrs", "d", levels(x), fixed=TRUE)
```

Nothing about this is really unique to factors. This is just how `sub()` works with any character vector, and `levels()` just happens to return a character vector.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick!  This makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

A convenient option is `fct_recode` from `forcats`

```
library(forcats)
fct_recode(x, d = "89+ hrs")
#[1] a b c d
#Levels: d a b c
```

#### data

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "89+ hrs"))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun.  This looks like a brilliantly simple solution that I'll keep for later, but didn't tell me why I had trouble with the + sign.