# Replacing Values in a column

Tags: r

A column has different values, one of which includes value `*`.
I want to replace that with `U`.

data looks something like this :
col 
    f
    f
    g
    h
    *
    t
    *

## i

I have tried below options:

```
replace( df$col, "*", "U")
data$PROP_TYPE[df$col=='*'] <- 'U'
```

Both do not work

Comment: Please include at least a few rows of sample data from your data frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with special characters like \^$.?\*|+()\[{ in my regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` needs to know which elements to replace (the `x == "*"`):

```
x <- c("*", "a", "*", "a", "*", "a", "*", "a", "B")
replace(x, x == "*", "U")
#[1] "U" "a" "U" "a" "U" "a" "U" "a" "B"
```

In `data.frame`

```
df <- data.frame(x = x, stringsAsFactors = F)
df[df$x == "*", "x"] <- "U"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how often `*` shows up in your data frame, but you can use `gsub` to replace all instances of it.

Say you have a column like this:

```
df <- c("asd*asd", "432*432", "*")
[1] "asd*asd" "432*432" "*"
```

If you want to replace all the `*` with `U` then you can run this

```
gsub("\\*", "U", df)
[1] "asdUasd" "432U432" "U"
```

Since `*` is a special character, you have to escape it using `\\` or else it will not give you what you're looking for.