# Deleting strings between tags ()

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a data frame with a few tags < > , [ ] ,and ( )

I need to delete the tags and whatever is between them.

I tried

`sub("<.*>", "", df)
sub("(.*)", "", df)
sub("[.*]", "", df)`

It works fine for the < > and [ ] tags but it does not work for ( ) tags.
Thx

Comment: you probably need to escape them, try `sub("\\(.*\\)", "", df)`

Comment: @jay.sf too simple...thx it worked. I tried escaping with only on \ but that didn't do the trick; now its working

Comment: You may want to read this for enlightenment :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/27721009/6574038

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this expression is likely to work here,

```
([<\(\[].*?[>\]\)])
```

and our code might look like:

```
sub("([\\<\\(\\[].*?[\\>\\]\\)])", "", df)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vc33Je/1/)

Comment: That doesn't work as it says :
Error: '\(' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""([<\("

Comment: In R, you need a double backslash \\ to escape special characters.

Comment: Your regex matches `[asdf>`

Comment: Validating ? Every time you write a regex your _validating_ !! Otherwise all regex would be `.+`

Comment: It is really more than matching specific data that the question poses. That is naivete.

Comment: @sln would be nice if you tell me what you mean by "That is naivete"