# What is wrong with this gsub one liner

Tags: r, gsub

This may be a silly question, but its doing my head in. I have always used gsub, but for some reason, it isnt working for this one:

Example of dataset

```
ColumnS
I 2,[3],4:i:-
I 2,[3],4:i:-
I 2,[3],4:b:-
Give
Derby
Panama
Kentucky
```

This is what I've been trying

```
dataset$ColumnS<-gsub("I 2,[3],4","2,[3],4", dataset$ColumnS)
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: You need to escape the square brackets or add `fixed = TRUE`. Try `gsub("I 2,[3],4:", "2,3,4", 'I 2,[3],4:i:-', fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with special characters like \^$.?\*|+()\[{ in my regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex)

Comment: Thank you Sotos! the fixed=TRUE worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square brackets are special characters when it comes to pattern recognition and if you want to match them, you have to use escape characters to inform R.

`dataset$ColumnS <- gsub("I 2,\\[3\\],4","2,[3],4", dataset$ColumnS)`

You can also use the argument `fixed=TRUE` which will take the pattern as a string.

`dataset$ColumnS <- gsub("I 2,[3],4","2,[3],4", dataset$ColumnS, fixed=TRUE)`