# Several find and replace from text file

Tags: r, regex, ms-word, gsub

I have a text file which want to convert it to data frame. The text is messy, and needs cleaning, removing a couple of repetitive sentences, replace new line (the wildcard in word is "^p" to tab or comma and ...

for example my text file is like:

```
-The data 1 is taken on Aug, 2009 at UBC
and is significant with p value <0.01

-The data 2 is taken on Sep, 2012 at SFU
and is  not significant with p value > 0.06
```

how can I can I do multiple find and replace.
I used this code:

```
tx = readLines("My_text.txt")
tx2 = gsub(pattern = "is taken on", replace = " ", x = tx)
tx3 = gsub(pattern = "at", replace = " ", x = tx2)
writeLines(tx3, con="tx3.txt")
```

But I do not know how can I replace "at" to tab (^t) or how can I replace (^p) with , or for example space^p ( ^p) with ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the regex supplied by jay.sf, you could use `str_replace_all` from the `stringr` package to do it with a named vector.

```r
library(stringr)

new_tx <- str_replace_all(tx,
                          c("\\sis taken on\\s" = " ",
                            "\\b\\sat\\s" = "\t",
                            "\\b\\sp\\b" = ","))

cat(new_tx)
```

**Result**

```r
-The data 1 Aug, 2009    UBC
and is significant with, value <0.01

-The data 2 Sep, 2012    SFU
and is  not significant with, value > 0.06
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [regular expressions](https://regex101.com/) to take account for word boundaries `\\b`.

To avoid multiple `gsub()` we could use a replacement matrix `rmx`.

```
rmx <- matrix(c("\\sis taken on\\s\\b", " ",  
                "\\b\\sat\\s", "\t"          #  replace with tab
                ), 2)        
#      [         ,1]                   [,2]         
# [1,] "\\sis taken on\\s\\b" "\\b\\sat\\s"
# [2,] " "                    "\t"
```

Now we may feed `gsub()` with `rmx` column by column using `apply()`. To make permanent changes to `tx` we can use the `<<-` operator. To avoid spamming the console, we could wrap the whole thing with an `invisible()`.

```
tx <- readLines("My_text.txt")
invisible(
  apply(rmx, MARGIN=2, function(x) tx <<- gsub(x[1], x[2], tx))
  )
```

To get continuous text rather than paragraphs (what I assume you mean by `^p`-replacement) we could simply `paste()` the result, `collapse`ing by `,`. The empty strings should be filtered out with `tx != ""`.

```
tx <- paste(tx[tx != ""], collapse=", ")
```

Now `writeLines()`.

```
writeLines(tx, con="tx4.txt")
```

**Result**

> -The data 1 Aug, 2009 UBC, and is significant with p value <0.01, -The data 2 Sep, 2012   SFU, and is  not significant with p value > 0.06

**Appendix**

We also may replace special characters in R by double-escape them – read [*this post*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27721008/6574038).

```
gsub("\\$", "\t", "today$is$monday")
# [1] "today\tis\tmonday"
```

Comment: thanks. for tab we can use : \t as you mentioned. But what about selecting next line or paragraph?
in word we use ^t for tab and ^p for paragraph. but here \p did not work for me.

Comment: I also noticed that if we have special characters like ($) in your find terms, it won't work. 
For example I cannot replace "today$is$monday" with "\t"

Comment: @Lionette Ahaaa, I didn't realize the "word-code", since I'm not working with it. I assume now you want to connect the paragraphs by commas. See update. I'm sure you may refine this solution to your specific needs.