# How to replace or remove data from dataframe which has '?' in it in R?

Tags: r, filter, data-cleaning

I have a dataset where few data are "?"(see below image for reference)

workclass has a single "?" in this sample data

```
age         workclass fnlwgt     education education_num         marital_status
39         State-gov  77516     Bachelors            13          Never-married
31           Private  45781       Masters            14          Never-married
42           Private 159449     Bachelors            13     Married-civ-spouse
30           Private 188146       HS-grad             9     Married-civ-spouse
30           Private  59496     Bachelors            13     Married-civ-spouse
44           Private 343591       HS-grad             9               Divorced
44           Private 198282     Bachelors            13     Married-civ-spouse
32      Self-emp-inc 317660       HS-grad             9     Married-civ-spouse
17                 ? 304873          10th             6          Never-married
28           Private 377869  Some-college            10     Married-civ-spouse
38  Self-emp-not-inc 120985       HS-grad             9     Married-civ-spouse
40       Federal-gov  56795       Masters            14          Never-married
```

[sample of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k52M.jpg)
I have tried filter, where and few other matching functions but it doesnt capture the ? in a string or int as well.

I am new to R language and not able to get a solution for this.

I want to get a count of data which has "?" in it and then based on the count decide to remove the rows or fill it with some meaningful data.

UPDATE :::

I data was " ?" rather than "?".
Couldnt make out by looking at it
Once i got that info was able to handle it.
It was a human error rather than the data/code i was trying :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with special characters like \^$.?\*|+()\[{ in my regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex)

Comment: `i <- which(df$workclass == "?")` Then use the index `i` to your desired effect. `length(i)` gives the count of `"?"`, for instance.

Comment: `dplyr`:  `filter(df, workclass=="?")` or use `grepl` inside `filter`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is called "df", you can get the count by running: `sum(df$workclass == "?")`

I would consider converting these values to proper NA-values, for example by running: `df$workclass <- ifelse(df$workclass == "?", NA, df$workclass)`.

Once you have them converted to NAs, you may for instance remove them by `na.omit(df)` or you could use imputation techniques like mode imputation or KNN-imputation, to name a few. You may read more about imputation techniques and handling of missing values here: https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-missing-data-handling-b94b8b5d2184

Comment: Just tried this method to convert the ? to NA but it changed the string values from---------
State-gov         Self-emp-not-inc  Private           Federal-gov     
[5]  Local-gov         ?                 Self-emp-inc      Without-pay     
[9]  Never-worked
----------------
to
-----------------
[1]  8  7  5  2  3 NA  6  9  4
----------
i just ran unique before and after converting ? to NA

Comment: I am not sure why that wouldn't work, but you could also try:

`df$workclass[df$workclass == "?"] <- NA`

Answer (score 0):

**To remove:**

revised_df = df [ -which ( df$workclass == "?" ) , ]

**To replace:** Let's say with "a"

df [ which ( df$workclass == "?" ) , "workclass"] = "a"