# How can I get rid of one backslash in a string in R?

Tags: r, regex, string, character

How can I remove all backslashes from this string?

```
t1 <- "1\2\3\4\5"
```

Output:

```
"1\002\003\004\005"
```

desired output:

```
"1002003004005"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Those are not backslashes, those are unicode letters.

Comment: @Pascal you can verify it using `writeLines(t1)`. Unable to share you the output as those as unicodes. Try yourself.

Comment: Really, getting that output from that input is not easy or advisable on a few levels. You could perhaps start with `sub("^[^]]*\\]\\s*", "", capture.output(charToRaw(t1)))`, which yields `"31 02 03 04 05"`, but that's obviously flawed due to the `31` (which is the raw bit encoding for the `"1"` character). It's easy enough string-wise to convert spaces and such, but ... to me, it sounds like there might be wrong assumptions about that data if you want `"1002"` from `"1\2"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is tricky, because `"1\002\003\004\005"` isn't really a valid string to begin with. To see this:

```
> writeLines(t1)
1
```

However, we can first `deparse` it to create valid string.

```
t2 <- deparse(t1)
> t2
[1] "\"1\\002\\003\\004\\005\""
```

And then use a regular `gsub` to remove the `\` and quotes we added as a side effect.

```
t3 = gsub('\\', '', t2, fixed = TRUE)
t3 = gsub('\"', '', t3)
```

More ideally, we'd write a compound regex.

```
t3 = gsub('[(\")(\\)]', '', t2)
> t3
[1] "1002003004005"
```

Edit: As a oneliner:

```
gsub('[(\")(\\)]', '', deparse(t1))
```

You can refer below link for more details on the pattern mapping using gsub:

[How do I deal with special characters like \^$.?*|+()[{ in my regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex)

https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
stringr::str_remove_all(stringi::stri_escape_unicode(t1), "\\\\u0")
```

gives output as

```
[1] "1002003004005"
```