# R find string in file that starts with "***"

Tags: r

I have a file that contains a specific line that begins with "***" How can I find the line with this string since it begins with wild cards?

I would normally use

```
Line_n <- grep("*** The Maximum 1hour", readLines(con=filename))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, you can use double backlashes to escape special characters in R. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: or change `grep()`'s argument  `fixed = TRUE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s <- c("** The Maximum 1hour", "*** The Maximum 1hour", 
       "*** The Maximum 2hours", "The Maximum 1hour", 
       "*** The Maximum 1hour", "+++ The Maximum 1hour",
       "dummy *** The Maximum 1hour")

grep("^[*]{3} The Maximum 1hour", s)
[1] 2 5
```

finds strings with exactly 3 asterisks at the beginning of the string (but only then).