# How to replace string with combination special characters in R

Tags: r, string, replace

This string which contains the encoding text of a zero-width space (<U+200B>) within it (part of a much larger string/character vector). I am trying to remove <U+200B> from within the string to '[#/volume]'

```
txv <- '[#/<U+200B>volume]' <br/>
txv  <- gsub(pattern = '<U+200B>',  replace = '', x = txv)
```

or

tried a few things including "\\<"+"U"+"\\+"+"200B"+"\\>"

```
txv <-str_replace(txv,'<U+200B>', '')
```

nothing seems to work

Comment: `gsub("<U+200B>", "", txv, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex