# Using R Separate_Rows doesn't work with a "|"

Tags: r, dplyr

Have a CSV file which has a column which has a variable list of items separated by a `|`.

I use the code below:

```
violations <- inspections %>% head(100) %>% 
  select(`Inspection ID`,Violations) %>% 
  separate_rows(Violations,sep = "|")
```

but this only creates a new row for each character in the field (including spaces)

What am I missing here on how to separate this column?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex

Comment: it's probably due to the fact that separate rows uses regex try `separate_rows(Violations,sep = '\\|')`

Comment: Appreciate the feedback on how my question can be better and will look to increase the information presented in any future ones.

Comment: It seems like the '\\|" suggestion solved my problem.  Appreciate the suggestion Abdessabour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to help without a better description of your data and an example of what the correct output would look like. That said, I think part of your confusion is due to the documentation in `separate_rows`. A similar function, `separate`, documents its `sep` argument as:

> If character, sep is interpreted as a regular expression. The default value is a regular expression that matches any sequence of non-alphanumeric values.

but the documentation for the `sep` argument in `separate_rows` doesn't say the same thing *though I think it has the same behavior*. In regular expressions, `|` has special meaning so it must be escaped as `\\|`.

```r
df <- tibble(
  Inspection_ID = c(1, 2, 3),
  Violations = c("A", "A|B", "A|B|C"))
separate_rows(df, Violations, sep = "\\|")
```

Yields

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Inspection_ID Violations
          <dbl> <chr>     
1             1 A         
2             2 A         
3             2 B         
4             3 A         
5             3 B         
6             3 C
```

Comment: Great to hear. Could you please mark your question as answered when you get a chance?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your data looks like, but you may want to replace `sep = "|"` with `sep = "\\|"`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using sep=‘\|’ with the separate_rows function allowed me to separate pipe delimited values