# how to remove records in R with * in example below using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
id: 1 1 2 2 3 3
key: ab a*b c*d*e cde a*3 3
```

I simply want `id` as `1 2 3` and `key` as `ab cde 3`.

So basically remove each record with `*` in the key.

Thanks

Comment: for key variable: some of the records are with * sign. like a*b, c*d*e, a*3

Comment: Are you looking to remove the `*` in `key`? Try `gsub('\\*', '', key)`

Comment: I want to delete that entire now where key has *. So i have two count of 6 rows, where 3 of those rows have key with * values, so i basically want the remaining 3 rows records without *. Hope that makes sense..thank you.

Comment: Next time it would be useful to post your data using `dput`. Here are some tips on how to create a minimal reproducible example for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/12400385

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grepl` to find all values of `key` with a `*`. Because `*` is a [special character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27721008/12400385), you have to use `\\` to match it. `!` will negate the match.

The `dplyr` way

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(!grepl('\\*', key))

#----------
  id key
1  1  ab
4  2 cde
6  3   3
```

Or using the full `tidyverse` which gives your `stringr::str_detect`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% filter(str_detect(key, '\\*', negate = TRUE))
```

---

Equivalents in base R

```
subset(df, !grepl('\\*', key))
```

Or

```
df[!grepl('\\*', df$'key'),]
```

---

```
# Data
df <- data.frame(id= c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                 key= c('ab', 'a*b', 'c*d*e', 'cde', 'a*3', 3 ))
```