# how to interpret the example of package glue for the item "backslashes do need to be doubled"

Tags: r, r-glue

how to interpret the code below , how R treat and evaluate it and get the result "foo",it is hard to understand for me

```
  `foo}\`` <- "foo"
glue("{
      {
        '}\\'' # { and } in comments, single quotes
        \"}\\\"\" # or double quotes are ignored
        `foo}\\`` # as are { in backticks
      }
  }")
#> foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not the only one to [find this example difficult to read](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/issues/147).
First, a variable with a funny name is created, and assigned the value "foo":

```
`foo}\`` <- "foo"
`foo}\``
[1] "foo"
```

Then `glue` should evaluate an R expression contained in the first level of curly braces, and itself contained in curly braces:

```
{
 '}\\'' 
 \"}\\\"\" # or double quotes are ignored
 `foo}\\`` # as are { in backticks
}
```

As it's a string, backslashes are used [to be able to write special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27721009/13513328).

When R parses each line of the expression, it converts the special characters to their value, and removes the comments after `#`.

The first line of the expression becomes

```
parse(text = "'}\\''")
expression('}\'')
> eval(expression('}\''))
[1] "}'"
```

The second line of the expression becomes:

```
> parse(text='\"}\\\"\"')
expression("}\"")
> eval(expression("}\""))
[1] "}\""
```

And finally the last line:

```
> parse(text = "`foo}\\``")
expression(`foo}\``)
> eval(expression(`foo}\``))
[1] "foo"
```

To sum up, we have :

```
{
"}'"
"}\""
"foo"
}

[1] "foo"
```