# R Markdown code chunk does not show math equations

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown

Basically i want to build a random multiple choice question generator with R Markdown. For this task there need to be equations in the code chunks of the markdown.

The following works like a charm and gives the equation "greekbeta = 1"

````
---
title: "test"
author: "me"
output:
    word_document: default
---

```{r eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE,results = "asis"}
"$\beta = 1$"
```
````

In contrast, this will not work when some other math symbol is used, for example:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "me"
output:
    word_document: default
---

```{r eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE,results = "asis"}
"$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$"
```
````

After pressing knit, an error occurs (unfortunately the error message is in german, basically this: "'\s' is an unknown escape-sequence within the string starting with "$/s"").

I am very puzzled by this, especially because for example \frac{1}{2} works, but \hat{x} does not.  Equations in the "normal" markdown text are no problem at all. But for my task, the equations have to be in the code chunk sections.

Does someone has a workaround for this problem? I tried using "$\hat{x}$" or even "$$\hat{x}$", but the error message is still the same.
I am using pandoc 2.11.4, R 4.1.0 and knitr 1.33

Comment: If you are creating an R chunk, you need to have valid R code in there. It doesn't look like you are trying to write R code at all there.  Why not move `$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$` outside of the R code chunk into the document itself?

Comment: There is no R code in this example, because i wanted to keep the section short.  But in the real thing there will be r code (choose a question at random from an excel table plus a random ordering of the answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `cat()` and [escape the escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27721008/6574038).

````
---
title: "test"
author: "me"
output:
    word_document: default
---

```{r eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE,results = "asis"}
cat("$\\beta = 1$", '\n\n')
cat("$a^2+b^2 = c^2$", '\n\n')
cat("$\\sum_{n=1}^{\\infty}x_i$", '\n\n')
```
````

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! I tried cat() before, but only with one backslash. With two backslashes, this is absolutely no problem.