# gsub unable to remove empty brackets in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have the following string in R

```
A<-"A (23) 56 hh()"
```

I want to get the following output

```
"A (23) 56 hh"
```

I tried the following code

```
B<-gsub(pattern = "()", replacement = "", x = A)
```

That didnt yield the desired result. How can I accomplish the same

Comment: See - [How do I deal with special characters like \^$.?*|+()[{ in my regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex)

Answer (score 4):

Try `fixed = TRUE` in `gsub`

```
> gsub("()", "", A, fixed = TRUE)
[1] "A (23) 56 hh"
```

Answer (score 4):

try `B<-gsub(pattern = "\\(\\)", replacement = "", x = A)`

`\\` indicates that it is a specific character - not the regex expression in brackets

Answer (score 4):

dy_by and ThomasIsCoding have good answers. Here is a modification of dy_by's answer

```
gsub(pattern = "\\()", replacement = "", x = A)

[1] "A (23) 56 hh"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(A, fixed("()"))
```

-ouptut

```
[1] "A (23) 56 hh"
```

Comment: Hi master akrun. Need your help. How  could I regex `(, 1, 0, )` to `10`

Comment: Try with `gsub("\\D+", "", str1)#
[1] "10"`

Answer (score 3):

Another option defining removal of two consecutive parenthesis chars, which obviates the need for fixed=TRUE:

```
library(stringr)

A %>% str_remove("[()]{2}")

[1] "A (23) 56 hh"
```