# Regex for Exact Title Search not working if title contains?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have list of song titles like these

**And Can It Be That I Should Gain?**

Problem is when i do an exact case insensitive search ? is treated as regex character and i dont get search results as expected.

So how do i encode song title so title itslef is not treated as regex

Please advise

```
{
  "data.title": {
    "$regex": "^And Can It Be That I Should Gain?$",
    "$options": "i"
  }
}
```

Comment: How to deal with special characters (in regex): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex

Comment: Just escape the question mark ``\?``.

Comment: You can escape with backslash. `\?` Why are you using regex for an exact match for the whole line?

Comment: I generate this JSON string in C#, and I wont know what kind of spcial chars Title will have? I;ll use this and see if it solves the problem Regex.Escape(String)