# Reading character vector in R

Tags: r, character

What is the best way to read this type of character vector?

`"global warming" OR "carbon sink" OR biodiversity OR conservation OR "global change"`

and transform it to

`"global+warming"+OR+"carbon+sink"+OR+biodiversity+OR+conservation+OR+"global+change"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like:

```
s <- '"global warming" OR "carbon sink" OR biodiversity OR conservation OR "global change"'
cat(gsub(" ", "+", s))
#"global+warming"+OR+"carbon+sink"+OR+biodiversity+OR+conservation+OR+"global+change"
```

Without `"`.

```
cat(gsub('"', "", gsub(" ", "+", s)))
#global+warming+OR+carbon+sink+OR+biodiversity+OR+conservation+OR+global+change
```

Comment: Yes, can you capture the printed output without the back slashes and first and last `"`?

Comment: `x <- gsub(" ", "+", s)` will capture it in `x`. You don't what it to start and end with `"`?

Comment: Yes, remove the first and the last `"`, as well as all `\\`

Comment: Is the result of `gsub('"', "", gsub(" ", "+", s))` what you want?

Comment: No, I need the output from `gsub(" ", "+", s)` but without backslashes

Comment: The backslashes are only shown on the terminal, escaping the `"` inside a character but they are not there. `cat` gives the string as it "really" is.

Comment: If I assign `gsub(" ", "+", s)` to a variable, the output is different from `cat(gsub(" ", "+", s))`

Comment: Yes. The output on the console is what will be needed to create this string, escaping all `"` inside the string. `"a\"b"` is in fact `a"b` and `cat` is showing it as it is, the console is showing `"`  escaped as `\"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245592/discussion-between-jmutua-and-gki).

Comment: See: [How do I deal with special characters like \^$.?*|+()[{ in my regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27721008/10488504)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want ?

```
text <- c("global warming" , "OR" , "carbon sink" , "OR" , "biodiversity" , "OR" , "conservation" , "OR" , "global change")

gsub(" " , "+" , do.call(paste , as.list(text)))
```

Comment: Nice try, you missed the quotation marks inside the output text `global+warming"+OR+"carbon+sink"+OR+biodiversity+OR+conservation+OR+"global+change"`

Comment: What is the character vector you have ?

Comment: Here is a subset `"climate change" OR "climate crisis" OR "global warming" OR "carbon sink" OR biodiversity OR conservation OR "global change"` and I need an output like this `"climate+change"+OR+"climate+crisis"+OR+"global+warming"+OR+"carbon+sink"+OR+biodiversity+OR+conservation+OR+"global+change"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is read from a file `/tmp/test` you could try something like this:

```r
st = readLines('/tmp/test')
gsub('\\s+', '+', gsub('\\\\|\\"', '', st))
```

Comment: Thanks, you missed the quotation marks inside the desired result