# ways to remove N/As from the columns in R

Tags: r, na, numeric

I am trying to convert the character column values to numeric, so I can divide one column by another later on. I get N/A values. I figured it might be because of commas. I tried to use the following code:

```
col1 <- c("L1","L2","L3","L4","L5" )
col2 <- c("910", "458", "34,613" , "201" , "1,886")
col3 <- c("87,282","41,304", "5,146,982", "348,520", "27,274")
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$col2 <-as.factor(df$col2)
df$col3 <-as.factor(df$col3)
#Convert chr to numeric
df[,'col2'] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[,'col2']))
#> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
df[,'col3'] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[,'col3']))
#> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
#try to get rid of commas
gsub(",", "", df$col3)
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA
df$new <- df$col3/df$col2
Created on 2022-06-30 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

**I also tried:**

```
df[,'col2'] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[,'col2']))
#> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$col3))
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>
```

**I also tried this way, which does not produce N/As, but still has commas:**

```
 setClass("num.with.commas")
setAs("character", "num.with.commas", 
      function(from) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", from) ) )
colClasses=c('num.with.commas','factor','character','numeric','num.with.commas')
#it does not remove commas, but it has no N/As

Created on 2022-06-30 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

**And the last effort which produced only errors:**

```
 dft %>%
  mutate_all(funs(as.character(.)), col2, col3) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(gsub(",", "", .)), col2, col3) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(as.numeric(.)), col2, col3)
#> Error in dft %>% mutate_all(funs(as.character(.)), col2, col3) %>% mutate_all(funs(gsub(
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `parse_number` specifying the relevant columns in `across` (which could also be negated, e.g. `-col1`):

(`%>%` may be used as an alternative to `|>`.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

col1 <- c("L1","L2","L3","L4","L5" )
col2 <- c("910", "458", "34,613" , "201" , "1,886")
col3 <- c("87,282","41,304", "5,146,982", "348,520", "27,274")
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df2 <- df |> 
  mutate(across(c(col2, col3), parse_number))
#>   col1  col2    col3
#> 1   L1   910   87282
#> 2   L2   458   41304
#> 3   L3 34613 5146982
#> 4   L4   201  348520
#> 5   L5  1886   27274
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it works in console, but when I click on data frame object in an environment it still show commas.

Comment: You need to save the new object, i.e. `df2 <- df |> mutate( ...)`

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

col1 <- c("L1","L2","L3","L4","L5" )
col2 <- c("910", "458", "34,613" , "201" , "1,886")
col3 <- c("87,282","41,304", "5,146,982", "348,520", "27,274")
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-1, ~ str_remove(.x, ","))) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = T)
#>   col1  col2     col3
#> 1   L1   910    87282
#> 2   L2   458    41304
#> 3   L3 34613 5146,982
#> 4   L4   201   348520
#> 5   L5  1886    27274
```

---

Or in `base R`:

```
data.frame(type.convert(lapply(df, \(x) gsub(",", "", x)), as.is = T))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `dplyr` way:
Here we remove all special characters and wrap it around `is.numeric`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-col1, ~as.numeric(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", .))))
```

```
  col1  col2    col3
1   L1   910   87282
2   L2   458   41304
3   L3 34613 5146982
4   L4   201  348520
5   L5  1886   27274
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close with the `gsub`. Try this small function,

```
clean_num <- \(x) as.numeric(as.character(gsub('[,\\$\']', '', x)))
```

it removes everything you define in the brackets ([special chars need to be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex)).

```
clean_num(df$col2)
# [1]   910   458 34613   201  1886
```

To use it on defined columns of a data frame, do

```
cols <- c('col2', 'col3')
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], clean_num)
df
#   col1  col2    col3
# 1   L1   910   87282
# 2   L2   458   41304
# 3   L3 34613 5146982
# 4   L4   201  348520
# 5   L5  1886   27274
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5"), col2 = structure(c(1L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 2L), levels = c("$910", "1,886", "201", "34,613", 
"458"), class = "factor"), col3 = structure(c(5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
1L), levels = c("27,274", "348,520", "41,304", "5,146,982", "87,282"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

The best code that worked for my data was:

`df$col2 <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",df$col2))`

Somehow the `as.character` addition was causing errors. Thanks, everyone!