# Splitting Text to Two Columns Using a Separator in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to split the column using a separator `"|"` but unfortunately the suggestions in Stack Overflow which recommended using `separator()` is not working in my situation.

Can someone help me out here.

The data frame, I am using is given below:

```
structure(list(UniqueID = c("12M-MA | X1", "12M-MA | X2", 
"12M-MA | X3", "12M-MA | X4", "12M-MA | X5"
), Cost = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 412.86), Actuals = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 32), Forecast = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 21), Value_Actuals = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 28341), Value_Forecast = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 652431
), `Forecast Accuracy` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 8.51), `Max (Act vs Cons)` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 652431)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code which I have used and the one which is working is this:

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(writexl)
library(stringr)
Df<- read_excel("C:/X/X/X/X/YXZ-2023.xlsx"skip = 1)

Df <- Df %>% 
  separate(UniqueID,c("ABC","XYZ"),sep = "|")
```

The expectation is to get keep the column as is and get two more columns one with the name of "ABC" and the other with "XYZ".

**12-MA** should go into the column "**ABC**" and the other value such as **X1,X2,X3,X4,X5** should go into column "**XYZ**".

Can someone help me out and let me now what is it that I am doing wrong. This was the suggestion in stack over flow and everywhere but isn't working for me.

Comment: Try with escaping \\ the | -> `df %>% 
  separate(UniqueID,c("ABC","XYZ"),sep = "\\|", remove = FALSE)`

Comment: @TarJae This worked like a charm. Thank you so much. But can you explain why we use "\\" here when the separator is just a "|" ?

Comment: @TarJae Can you please clarify the use of **"\\"**

Comment: \\ in R escapes special characters. See here  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex>! Here is a list of special characters. <https://www.webopedia.com/definitions/special-character/#:~:text=A%20special%20character%20is%20one,marks%20are%20also%20special%20characters.>

Comment: @TarJae Can you please post this as Answer. So that I can mark this as Correct answer and complete the question. And Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the newer `separate_wider_delim` with `cols_remove = F`?

```
require(tidyverse)
# require(tidyr) # if you do not want to import `tidyverse`

Df %>% separate_wider_delim(UniqueID, delim = "|", names = c("ABC", "XYZ"), cols_remove = F)
Df %>% separate_wider_delim(UniqueID, delim = " | ", names = c("ABC", "XYZ"), cols_remove = F) # if you do not want " " in the new columns

# A tibble: 5 × 10
  ABC    XYZ   UniqueID     Cost Actuals Forecast Value_Actuals Value_Forecast `Forecast Accuracy` `Max (Act vs Cons)`
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>               <dbl>               <dbl>
1 12M-MA X1    12M-MA | X1   0.2       0        0             0              0                0                      0
2 12M-MA X2    12M-MA | X2   0.3       0        0             0              0                0                      0
3 12M-MA X3    12M-MA | X3   0.2       0        0             0              0                0                      0
4 12M-MA X4    12M-MA | X4   0.2       0        0             0              0                0                      0
5 12M-MA X5    12M-MA | X5 413.       32       21         28341         652431                8.51              652431
```

Comment: Which library has this function?

Comment: @user20203146 I edited the answer to include the library. It's `tidyr`. Since you are already using packages from the `tidyverse`, I would recommend simply importing everything with `require(tidyverse)` (after installing it with `install.packages(tidyverse)`.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. But tidyr and tidyverse does not have this function. The function which does this function as per tidyr is **separate()** . When I run this function it gives the result **could not find the function separate_wider_delim**.

Comment: @user20203146 Then you most likely have an old version of `tidyverse` or `tidyr` installed. It is definitely a `tidyr` function (see https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_wider_delim.html).

Comment: Alright. Let me update the library and see.

Comment: It worked. I have one question. It still keeps space after the text or before the text. How to ensure that text is not present while splitting it?

Answer (score 1):

We have to escape `|` with: `\\`

`\\` in R escapes special characters. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex).

[Here](https://www.webopedia.com/definitions/special-character/#:%7E:text=A%20special%20character%20is%20one,marks%20are%20also%20special%20characters) is a list of special characters.

To keep the original column we use `remove = FALSE` argument.

Finally we use `across` with `trimws` to remove spaces.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%    
  separate(UniqueID,c("ABC","XYZ"),sep = "\\|", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(ABC, XYZ), trimws))

 UniqueID    ABC    XYZ    Cost Actuals Forecast Value_Actuals Value_Forecast `Forecast Accuracy` `Max (Act vs Cons)`
  <chr>       <chr>  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>               <dbl>               <dbl>
1 12M-MA | X1 12M-MA X1      0.2       0        0             0              0                0                      0
2 12M-MA | X2 12M-MA X2      0.3       0        0             0              0                0                      0
3 12M-MA | X3 12M-MA X3      0.2       0        0             0              0                0                      0
4 12M-MA | X4 12M-MA X4      0.2       0        0             0              0                0                      0
5 12M-MA | X5 12M-MA X5    413.       32       21         28341         652431                8.51              652431
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is with `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(UniqueID,
          c("ABC", "XYZ"),
          "(.*)\\s\\|\\s(.*)")
# A tibble: 5 × 9
  ABC    XYZ    Cost Actuals Forecast Value_Actuals Value_Forecast `Forecast Accuracy` `Max (Act vs Cons)`
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>               <dbl>               <dbl>
1 12M-MA X1      0.2       0        0             0              0                0                      0
2 12M-MA X2      0.3       0        0             0              0                0                      0
3 12M-MA X3      0.2       0        0             0              0                0                      0
4 12M-MA X4      0.2       0        0             0              0                0                      0
5 12M-MA X5    413.       32       21         28341         652431                8.51              652431
```