# How to find two threes in zip code using r

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-processing

I need help with this task:
Print data for locations that have two threes in the address.zip code.
I tried:

```
filtered_data <- df %>%
  filter(grepl("\\d{3}.*\\d{3}", address.zip))
  print(filtered_data)
```

It does not give any outputs, but I know there are zip codes with two threes in the data file

Comment: `\\d{3}` means a digit that appears three times. It doesn't mean the literal digit "3". Try `3.*3` It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Some good links for regex: https://regex101.com, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27721009/3358272. It's a lot to take in, but ... regex is a lot, and it's not hard to get it _wrong_.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(stringr)
d <- data.frame(
  zipcode = c("00001", "10003", "20003", "30003"), 
  addr = c("123 Main", "456 Maple", "789 Mulberry", "12302 Arrow")
)

d[which(str_count(d$zipcode,"3") == 2),"zipcode"]
[1] "30003"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what **exactly** you need to filter here are two solutions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
```

You want to filter zipcodes where the two `3`s are immediately adjacent:

```
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(zipcode, "33"))
  zipcode
1   83310
```

You want to filter zipcodes with two `3`s occurring in any order:

```
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(zipcode, "3.*3"))
  zipcode
1   83310
2   35389
3   73123
```

Here, the pattern `3.*3` matches a `3` followed by any character (`.`) occurring 0 or more times (`*`) followed by `3`

Toy data:

```
 df <- data.frame(
   zipcode = c("90001", "83310", "35389", "73123")
 )
```