# Regular expression to capture single digit between two periods

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe column called `day_survey_prompt` that contains strings from 1.1.1 to 14.8.112. The first number increases sequentially from 1 to 14, the second number from 1 to 8, and the third from 1 to 112. I am trying to write a regular expression to capture the middle number, which is always a single digit 1 through 8, and not the two periods around it.

I have tried many regular expressions, including lookbehinds and lookaheads, and they always capture one or both periods in addition to the middle digit. For example, when the value of day_survey_prompt is 14.5.85

`str_extract(day_survey_prompt, "[^.]*$")`

yields `85` and

`str_extract(day_survey_prompt, "[^.]*[.$]")`

yields `14.`

My desired output in this example is `5`

What is the regular expression that will get me there?

Answer (score 2):

Up front: in your expressions, `[^.]` means "not the literal dot", which when followed by a `*` ("zero or more") could match anything other than a dot. Similarly, `[.$]` is a character group that matches either the literal dot or a literal dollar-sign; if you were intending to say "a dot or end-of-string, then `([.]|$)` would be better in that regard. Similarly, `(^|[.])` would mean "beginning of string or a literal dot".

---

Perl regex extraction using lookbehind (`(?<=...)`) and lookahead (`(?=...)`):

```r
ch <- c("14.8.112", "14.5.85")
regmatches(ch, gregexpr("(?<=[.])[0-9]+(?=[.])", ch, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "8"
# [[2]]
# [1] "5"
```

`gsub`-replacement, assuming you always have a number between two periods *somewhere* and don't care what is outside of the periods:

```r
gsub("^[^.]*\\.([0-9]+)\\..*", "\\1", ch)
# [1] "8" "5"
```

String-splitting on the `.`,

```r
strsplit(ch, "[.]")
# [[1]]
# [1] "14"  "8"   "112"
# [[2]]
# [1] "14" "5"  "85"
```

and extracting the second of each string:

```r
strsplit(ch, "[.]") |>
  sapply(`[[`, 2)
# [1] "8" "5"
```

If it's always a triad and you *might* ever want the first and third, we can extract them into a frame with

```r
strcapture("([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)", ch,
           proto=list(first=0L, second=0L, third=0L))
#   first second third
# 1    14      8   112
# 2    14      5    85
```

Using the `stringr` package (thanks to for the assists :-):

```r
# @AndyBaxter
stringr::str_extract(ch, "(?<=\\.)\\d(?=\\.)")
# @nightstand
stringr::str_extract(ch, "\\d{1,2}\\.(\\d)\\.\\d{1,3}", group=1)
```

(Noting that this example will collect single-digit numbers, nothing higher than `9`, so if you want `n`-digit numbers then use `\\d+` or `\\d{1,}`. Also the `{1,2}` and `{1,3}` are making assumptions based on your sample data, you may prefer `+` if the magnitude of the preceding/following numbers is unknown.)

---

Notes:

- since `.` is a regex thing that means "any character", we need to escape it. I've demonstrated two ways to do so, using either `\\.` (backslash-escape) or `[.]` (period in a `[`-group, which interprets the `.` as the literal period only), they can be used interchangeably.
- similarly, "digits" can be regexed as `[0-9]` or `\\d`, also interchangeable

Refs:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272 is a good reference for regex in general, note that its use of a single-backslash will generally need to be doubled for use in R;
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for "lookaround" functionality in general (not specific to R);
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27721009/3358272 has some R-specific nuances, though mostly just another reference to the above
- and of course, there is [`?regex`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) in R

Comment: These are all very handy! `str_extract(numbers, "(?<=\\.)\\d(?=\\.)")` would work too

Comment: Less elegant regex but you can also use `group` argument in `str_extract(ch, "\\d{1,2}\\.(\\d)\\.\\d{1,3}", group=1)`

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I have tried many regular expressions, including lookbehinds and lookaheads, and they always capture one or both periods in addition to the middle digit. ..."*

Try the following *match pattern*.

```
(?<=\d\.)[1-8](?=\.\d)
```

- `(?<=\d\.)`, positive look-behind, for a *digit* and a *period*
- `[1-8]`, matches a single digit, *1 through 8*
- `(?=\.\d)`, positive look-ahead, for a *period* and a *digit*

Or, a more accurate approach would be to use a *capture pattern*.

```
\b(?:1[0-4]|[1-9])\.([1-8])\.(?:11[0-2]|10\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9])\b
```

- `\b`, starts at a word-boundary
- `(?:1[0-4]|[1-9])`, matches the values, *1 through 14*
- `\.([1-8])\.`, captures the value within two *periods*
- `(?:11[0-2]|10\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9])`, matches the values, *1 through 112*
- `\b`, ends at a word-boundary