# R Rvest querying URLs returned

Tags: r, rvest

I am using `Rvest` to scrape some data, if I print my URLs variable I get:

```
[32] "soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=6"                                     

[33] "soccerstats.com/pmatch.asp?league=argentina&matchid=422&t1=5&t2=14&ly=2017" 

[34] "soccerstats.com/pmatch.asp?league=argentina&matchid=432&t1=23&t2=26&ly=2017"

[35] "soccerstats.com/pmatch.asp?league=argentina&matchid=425&t1=11&t2=10&ly=2017"
```

There is a mixture of URLs in the data set but I am only interested in the URLs that contain:

```
soccerstats.com/pmatch.asp?league=
```

I am trying to filter them by:

```
oversdf <- data.frame(URLs=URLs)

rownames(oversdf) # This returns 1,2,3,4 etc as expected

grep("^soccerstats.com/pmatch.asp?league",rownames(oversdf)) # This then doesn't return any results
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, I just want to return all URLs that contain a certain string only.

Cheers

---

library(rvest)

URL <- "http://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp" #Feed page

WS <- read_html (URL) #reads webpage into WS variable

URLs <- WS %>% html_nodes ("a:nth-child(1)") %>% html_attr("href") %>% as.character() # Get the CSS nodes & extract the URLs

URLs <- paste0("http://www.soccerstats.com/",URLs)

oversdf <- data.frame(URLs=URLs)

rownames(oversdf)  #returns a vector of row names in the overs data.frame:

grep("^pmatch.asp?league",oversdf$URLs)

Comment: It would be easier if we could see your code properly https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Meanwhile have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043928/selecting-rows-where-a-column-has-a-string-like-hsa-partial-string-match

Comment: `grep("^soccerstats.com/pmatch.asp?league",rownames(oversdf))` is searching for the string in the rownames. Change `rownames(oversdf)` to something like `oversdf$URLs`. The idea of the `grep` is to *return* the rownames which you then use as arguments to your data frame.

Comment: Hi @anotherfred, thanks for looking, I have tried the change above but its still returning no results, see full code:

Comment: library(rvest)<br><br>

URL <- "http://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp" #Feed page

WS <- read_html (URL) #reads webpage into WS variable

URLs <- WS %>% html_nodes ("a:nth-child(1)") %>% html_attr("href") %>% as.character() # Get the CSS nodes & extract the URLs 

URLs <- paste0("http://www.soccerstats.com/",URLs) 

oversdf <- data.frame(URLs=URLs)

rownames(oversdf)  #returns a vector of row names in the overs data.frame:

grep("^http://www.soccerstats.com/pmatch.asp?league",oversdf$URLs) <code>

Comment: @anotherfred I have posted the code in the original question above as cant seem to format in the comment section.

Comment: Looking at other forum posts this line should work, but doesnt in this case for some reason: grep("^pmatch.asp?league", oversdf$URLs)

Comment: You need to escape the '?' in your string. It has a special meaning in regular expressions.Put '\\' before it. (One '\' for R and one for grep - this is not the normal escape https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602433/how-to-escape-a-question-mark-in-r)

Comment: That works, thanks :)